# How can I pass data on redirect without using query strings with Express?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I'm building an Express app for the first time.

I have a function that checks if the user is logged in, if not it will redirect them to the /login page.

Inside this function I have the URL that the user requested stored as a variable.

I'm using res.redirect('/login') to redirect the login page, however I want to pass the originally requested URL to that route also, allowing the login route to log the user in and then redirect them to the originally requested page.

I've tried to set req.app.locals and res.app.locals to the data before redirecting but it seems like this data is lost on redirect.

Is there any way to do this without using query strings.

Cheers.

```
req.app.locals.requestedURL = err.requestedURL;
res.redirect('/login');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sessions can solve your issue. By using **[express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)** you can write code like:

```
req.session.requestedURL = "your-url-goes-here";
```

And in your /login route you can access the requested url using:

```
req.session.requestedURL
```